# Convert text to link base on char receive

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a post that contains a content body, the text in content body need to be properly formatted.
If the content contain a special keyword @, # i want to convert it to a usefull link.

```
 content = "These is a sample post it can contain any thing and i can mention people with @username and show hastag reference #stackoverflowQuestion";
    newContent = content.split(" ");
    username = [];
    hashtag = [];

    newContent.forEach((sub) => {
        at = sub.indexOf("@");
        tag = sub.indexOf("#");
        if(at == 0){
            trendname.push(sub)
        } 
       if(tag == 0){
            hashtag.push(sub)
        }
       return sub;
    });

    username.forEach((user) => {
        user.link = user.replace(/@/, "/${user}");console.log(user.link);
    return user;}); console.log(user.link);
   hashtag.forEach((str) => {
     str.taged= str.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2').toLowercase;
    return str;}); console.log(str.taged);
```

Firstly the code above is not loging vakue outside the loop.
Secondly is there any other way to re-write these sode because it look in efficient. if there is Please specify.
Thanks

Comment: It's not logging the value outside the loop because the variable doesn't exist outside the loop. Function arguments are scoped to the function body. You also need to declare variables with `let`, `const`, or `var`. Without one of those you're creating global variables, which is almost never what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is a little bit complicated to understand I think... But anyways I hope the following will help you somehow.

First, you can simplify your first loop to:

```
let usernames = content.match(/@([^ ]*)/g)
let hashtags = content.match(/#([^ ]*)/g)
```

Those are regex, and they work as follow:

1. They begin with `@` or `#` (if you are looking for usernames or hashtags)
2. `[^ ]*` means "Everything but a white space, and multiple times (`*`)

So now, you can construct user objects:

```
let users = usernames.map(username => {
    return {
        username: username,
        link: '/' + username.slice(1, username.length)
    }
}) // --> [ { username: '@username', link: '/username' } ]
```

Here is the complete code I wrote:

```
let content = "These is a sample post it can contain any thing and i can mention people with @username and show hastag reference #stackoverflowQuestion";

let usernames = content.match(/@([^ ]*)/g)
let hashtags = content.match(/#([^ ]*)/g)

let users = usernames.map(username => {
    return {
        username: username,
        link: '/' + username.slice(1, username.length)
    }
})

console.log(users)
```

Something is wrong with your code. You are making a `forEach` on an array of strings, and then you try to set a property to that string: `user.link = ...`.

Secondly, you are trying to log values outside of your loops, and doing so puts you out of the scope of the loop. So you can't log those variables and this is completely normal because they just don't exist anymore... Try to indent your code better, you'll see it directly.

Hope this helps, and try working a little bit on the redaction of your questions, the stack overflow community can be harsh some times

Comment: Thanks very much. you really simplify my code. It hard to understand because the string that start with @ or # will be converted to a link that is clickable. Just like any other social network.